# Run Parts of a Pipeline as Separate Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

We're considering using the Jenkins Pipeline plugin for a rather complex project consisting of several deliveries that need to be build using different tools (on different machines) before being merged. Still, it seems to be easy enough to do a complete build with a single `Jenkinsfile`, and I like the automatic discovery of git branches that comes with Pipeline.

However, at this point, we have jobs for each of the deliveries and use a build-flow based "meta" job to orchestrate the individual jobs. The nice thing about this is that it also allows starting just one individual job if only small changes were made, just to see whether this delivery still compiles.

To emulate this, some ideas came to mind:

- Use different `Jenkinsfile`s for the deliveries and `load` them in the top-level `Jenkinsfile`; it seems that the Multibranch Pipeline job does not allow configuring the `Jenkinsfile` to use yet (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35415), however, so creating the jobs for the individual deliveries is still open.
- Provide a configuration option for the "top-level" job and have `if`s for all deliveries in the `Jenkinsfile` to be able to select which should be build. This would mix different build types in one pipeline, though, and, at the very least, mess up the estimation of the build time.

Are those viable options, or is there a better one?

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129745/jenkins-build-pipeline-restart-at-stage although that one is about restarting. Still, answers to that question also hold fr this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is to write a pipelining script that has has "if"-guards around the single stages, like this:

```
stage "s1"
if (theStage in ["s1","all"]) {
    sleep 2
}

stage "s2"
if (theStage in ["s2", "all"]) {
    sleep 2
}

stage "s3"
if (theStage in ["s3", "all"]) {
    sleep 2
}
```

Then you can make a "main" job that uses this script and runs all stages at once by setting the parameter "theStage" to "all". This job will collect the statistics when all stages are run at once and give you useful estimation times.

Furthermore, you can make a "partial run" job that uses this script and that is parametrized with the stage that you want to run. The estimation will not be very useful, though.

Note that I put the stage itself to the main script and put only the execution code into the conditional, as suggested by Martin Ba. This makes sure that the visualization of the job is more reliable

Comment: This *is* a good idea, however: ["Dynamic stages: in general, if you want to visualize dynamically changing stages, make it conditional to execute the stage contents, not conditional to include the stage"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin)

Comment: Good advice. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an expansion of the previous answer, I would propose something like that:

```
def stageIf(String name, Closure body) {
if (params.firstStage <= name && params.lastStage >= name) {
    stage(name, body)
} else {
    stage(name) {
        echo "Stage skipped: $name"
    }
}
}

node('linux') {
properties([
        parameters([
                choiceParam(
                        name: 'firstStage',
                        choices: '1.Build\n' +
                                '2.Docker\n' +
                                '3.Deploy',
                        description: 'First stage to start',
                        defaultValue: '1.Build',
                ),
                choiceParam(
                        name: 'lastStage',
                        choices: '3.Deploy\n' +
                                '2.Docker\n' +
                                '1.Build',
                        description: 'Last stage to start',
                        defaultValue: '3.Deploy',
                ),
        ])
])

stageIf('1.Build') {
  // ... 
}
stageIf('3.Deploy') {
  // ... 
}
}
```

Not as perfect as I wish but at least its working.

Comment: This is a rather unique implementation given the limitations. Definitely an option.