# Multiple pipeline jobs versus single large pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am fairly new to Jenkins pipeline and am considering migrating an existing Jenkins batch to use pipeline script.

This may be an obvious question to those in the know but I have not been able to find any discussion of it anywhere. If you have a fairly complex set of jobs, say a few hundred, is it best practice to end up with one job with a fairly large script or a small number of jobs, probably parameterized, say 5 to 10, with smaller pipeline scripts that call each other.

Comment: Personally, I consider Jenkins Pipeline not yet ready for complex multi-job scenarios. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Having one huge job has the severe disadvantage that you cannot easily execute the single stages anymore. On the other hand, splitting everything into different jobs has the disadvantage that many of the nice pipeline features (shared variables, shared code) cannot be used anymore. I do not think that there is a unique answer to this.

Have a look at the following two related questions:

- [Jenkins Build Pipeline - Restart At Stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129745/jenkins-build-pipeline-restart-at-stage)
- [Run Parts of a Pipeline as Separate Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181980/run-parts-of-a-pipeline-as-separate-job)