# Triggers on specific stage Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins since a little moment now, but I wanted to do something and I can't find how to do it...

In deed, I want to trigger my projects with two differents way: every 4 hours and for every commit.
But for each case, I don't want that all my Jenkinsfile is executed, only some specific stages.

Is it possible to do that with Declarative Pipelines ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not available out of the box yet. Cloudbees has a proprietary plugin called "checkpoints" which can do that, [see plugin docs here](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#workflow-sect-checkpoint).

This plugin may be added in Jenkins by default in near future, [see this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846).

PS: This is duplicate of [Jenkins Build Pipeline - Restart At Stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129745/jenkins-build-pipeline-restart-at-stage) (can't mark it as duplicated)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look about it. For the duplicate, I've never seen this post, so sorry

Comment: Separate question, do you now how have the "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL" parameter in a pipeline ? (it come with GitLab plugin and GitLab hook plugin I think)