# Jenkins - how to resume pipeline from failure point

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a rather lengthy Jenkins pipeline that will sometimes fail for various reasons like a box running out of disk space, network issues, etc.

I would like to be able to manually resume the pipeline from the point that it previously failed and have it run all subsequent jobs in that pipeline as well. Currently, to accomplish this I have to individually run the steps which is rather time-consuming. Restarting the entire pipeline would be extremely time-consuming.

For example, in the below pipeline I failed at `Run L1 Batch` step. I would like to be able to have the pipeline start from the `Run L1 Batch` step, then `Run TB Maint`, and finally `Run JUnit/Jacoco` without manually running these individually in that sequence:

[image: Jenkins Pipeline Failure]

Does anyone know of a Jenkins plugin that allows you to resume pipeline execution from a specific point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129745/jenkins-build-pipeline-restart-at-stage

Comment: @Prikkeldraad wrapping in a retry would be ineffective for situations like running out of diskspace. Using the if-guards as mentioned in one of the answers isn't a bad suggestion, but given that my pipeline has sub-pipelines which have sub-sub-pipelines that would be extremely cumbersome. What I am really looking for is that Checkpoint plugin that CloudBees does not plan to open-source :(

Comment: Sounds like [JENKINS-33846](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846)/[JENKINS-45455](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45455)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the new feature to restart stages would help?

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45455